# How to find source URL to scrape a website

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to scrape https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ugaz?ltr=1 in order to get the UGAZ current quote.

I have referred some posts that tell you to 1>Click on the desired location 2> Click Inspect 3>Go to Network and find in the "Name" column the potential link. I do not know the "type" that needs to be selected in order to find "Request URL" link.

Please assist in the process.

Comment: In what context did you see advice to "Click on the desired location"?  Is this supposed to be inside the browser itself, or some specific app?

Comment: First, through the "inspect" of the site, you must identify the area of the HTML that interests you (F12 = inspect -> elements tab -> on the top left of the console, there is an arrow symbol. If you click on this arrow and then click on an area of the site itself, the HTML code for that particular item will be highlighted in the console). Then with some python library, like BeatifulSoup, start scraping site

Comment: The desired location for me is the current quote. $67.91. I would like to find the tag for this. Its inside the browser.

Comment: @ElidorDD I have scraped website before using beautiful soup but in order to scrape I need the source url that spits html code and in this website its difficult to find. I clicked on the area you mentioned and it does not have html characters like div, tr , th etc.

Comment: @Sid1980 sorry, I understand what the problem is. What you need is in inspect -> network tab -> XHR sub-tab -> examining the requests and responses of each network action, you can find what you URL you ought to be sending the GET request too.

Comment: @ElidorDD. Thanks. it worked.I have posted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing the various comments above, I tried to sketch a piece of code that works by returning current quote:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/UGAZ?region=US&lang=en-US&includePrePost=false&interval=2m&range=1d&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance')
data = r.json()
price = data['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['regularMarketPrice']
print(price)
```

Output

```
67.91
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to scrape the URL:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 res = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ugaz?ltr=1')
 soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
 tags = soup.find_all('span')[11]
 tags.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the price by using the `find` method. The `find` function searches for the specified class, which you can find from the web-page source code. The find method requires the html component and the class name, which you can only use a small part of. In this case, you can search for the `span` tag along with its `class` which is `Trsdu(0.3s)`, you can just use a part of the class name. This [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a good guide for the Beautiful Soup methods.

#### Example

```
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ugaz?ltr=1"
request = requests.get(url)
html_content = request.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
price = soup.find("span", class_="Trsdu(0.3s)")
print(price.text)
```

#### Output

```
67.91
```